# isnull and in statement in CAML

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml

Is it possible to combine the sharepoint `<In>` statement with the `<IsNull>` statement? I only managed to get it working using an `<Or>` but would be great if you could place the `<isNull>` inside the `<In>` directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

```
<Query>
   <Where>

      <In>
         <FieldRef Name='MyLookupField' LookupId='TRUE'/>
         <Values>
           <Value Type='Lookup'></Value>
           <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
         </Values>
      </In>

   </Where>
</Query>
```